# How to set value of Pandas Dataframe column based on a row above?

Tags: python, pandas

I've found apply and map great for speeding up calculations on particular rows in a DataFrame.

The question I've got is: Is it possible to return a value with apply or map functions which refer to a previous row?

For instance, I've got a timeseries column df['freezing'] that flags an event (such as whether temperatures fell below freezing).

I'd also like to create a column that answered the question: was it freezing in the previous interval (the row above (or potentially the row= row -x above))?

Apply and map are great at vectorising row by row calculations - is it possible to refer to the previous row so I can make that calculation?

Comment: look at [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas.Series.shift)

Comment: Can you post what you want to really achieve or are you asking for an example of how this could work?